# ¿Como propagar la excepción de una subclase?

Tags: python

Mi aplicación tiene una clase que interactua con una BD (o más), y hay un script que instancia la clase anterior y manda un mail si hubo un error.

En lo que tengo problemas es cómo hacer para manejar la excepción si el script que instancia la clase de la BD también es instanciado.

¿Hay alguna manera más fácil o "pythonica" de hacer lo que necesito?

Esto es lo que llevo hecho:

```py
#utils/db_utils.py
import mysql.connector

class DB_Manager():
    conf_dict = {
        'user': 'scott',
        'password': 'password',
        'host': '127.0.0.1',
        'database': 'employees',
        'raise_on_warnings': True
        }

    def __init__(self):
        self.abrir_db_conn(self.conf_dict)

    def abrir_db_conn(self, conf_dict):
        try:
            self.db_conn = mysql.connector.connect(**conf_dict)
        except Exception:
            print(f"Ha habido un error en la BD {self.conf_dict['database']}")
            raise
```

Después, creo una instancia de la clase donde manejo la BD:

```py
# main.py
from utils.db_utils import DB_Manager
class Mi_Subproceso():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def main(self):
        try:
            clase_db = DB_Manager()
        except Exception:
            print("Ha habido un error en la conexión")
            # Aquí mando un email informando que hubo un error en la BD
            if __name__ != "__main__":
                raise # ¿Esto es correcto para mandar la excepción a la otra clase?
```

Algo que puede pasar, es que haya un proceso más grande que ejecute esta clase y otras más, por ejemplo:

```py
# main_wrapper.py
from main import Mi_Subproceso
class Proceso_Completo():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def main(self):
        try:
            mi_proceso = Mi_Subproceso().main()
            mi_proceso2 = Mi_Subproceso().main()
        except Exception:
            print("Ha habido un error en alguno de los procesos")
            # Aquí mando un email informando que hubo un error en alguno de los subprocesos
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con tu implementación, siempre que instanciemos `Mi_Subproceso` **importando** el módulo la excepción se propagará, eso si, el mensaje debemos mandarlo después de comprobar `__name__` o lo enviarás tres veces...

```
from utils.db_utils import DB_Manager


class Mi_Subproceso:

    def main(self):
        try:
            clase_db = DB_Manager()

        except Exception:
            if __name__ != "__main__":
                raise
            print("Ha habido un error en la conexión")
            # Aquí mando un email informando que hubo un error en la BD
```

Solo hay un problema (o no, depende de lo que busques), si hacemos:

```
# main_wrapper.py
from main import Mi_Subproceso

Mi_Subproceso.main()
```

la excepción también se propaga, aunque no la estemos manejando, con lo que el mensaje no se mandaría.

Yo no me complicaría la vida demasiado, sería mucho más simple usar un parámetro del inicializador o del método `main` para permitir o no el manejo de la excepción y el envío del email en la propia clase, algo como:

```
from utils.db_utils import DB_Manager


class Mi_Subproces:
    def __init__(self, raise_except_on_err=False):
        self.raise_except_on_err = raise_except_on_err

    def main(self):
        try:
            clase_db = DB_Manager()
        except Exception:
            if self.raise_except_on_err:
                raise
            print("Ha habido un error en la conexión")
            # Aquí mando un email informando que hubo un error en la BD
```

y luego puedes hacer:

```
try:
    mi_proceso = Mi_Subproceso(raise_except_on_err=True).main()
    mi_proceso2 = Mi_Subproceso(raise_except_on_err=True).main()
except Exception:
    print("Ha habido un error en alguno de los procesos")
    # Aquí mando un email informando que hubo un error en alguno de los subprocesos
```

Comment: En "la excepción también se propaga, aunque no la estemos manejando, con lo que el mensaje no se mandaría." Es porque no se está haciendo el manejo de excepciones con el "try", ¿verdad? Y sí, esa idea de la bandera me gusta.